# C++ move constructor not called

Tags: c++, move-constructor

In the following (borrowed) example, in my environment the move constructor is never called:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
  public:
      MyClass()
      {
          std::cout << "default constructor\n";
      }
      MyClass(MyClass& a)
      {
          std::cout << "copy constructor\n";
      }

      MyClass(MyClass&& b)
      {
          std::cout << "move constructor\n";
      } 
};  

void test(MyClass&& temp)
{
    MyClass a(MyClass{}); // calls MOVE constructor as expected
    MyClass b(temp); // calls COPY constructor...  
}

int main()
{
    test(MyClass{});
    return 0;
}
```

My output is:
default constructor
default constructor
copy constructor

I use XCode version 9.1, shouldnt the move constructor be called on rvalue references? What am I missing here?

John.

Comment: `MyClass&& temp` is actually an lvalue at the point at which you call `MyClass b(temp);` (since it has a name); In order to call the rvalue constructor you need to *move* it (`MyClass b(std::move(temp));`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

The point is that everything that has a name is lvalue.

It means that named rvalue reference itself is lvalue and `temp` from:

```
void test(MyClass&& temp)
```

is lvalue as well. So move constructor is not called.

If you want a move constructor to be called, use `std::move`:

```
void test(MyClass&& temp)
{
    // ...
    MyClass b(std::move(temp)); // use std::move here 
}
```

By the way,

```
 MyClass(MyClass& a)
 {
     std::cout << "copy constructor\n";
 }
```

is not a copy constructor because copy constructor has a form of:

```
MyClass(const MyClass& a) { ... }
```

Comment: shouldnt this code:  MyClass a(MyClass{}); have to call the move constructor?

Comment: @JohnGorter it might, but in fact copy elision takes place: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision